# MySQL: Optionally Build Group Concat field

Tags: mysql, sql, conditional-statements, group-concat

I have a set of articles. Some of these articles have been assigned x number of tags.

I want to select all articles in the format specified in the `SELECT`, and if the article also has any number of tags assigned, put them into a single `GROUP_CONCAT` field.

The SQL below does everything I need, **except** *it only retrieves articles that have at least one tag*.

How can I make it so that the tagging requirement is optional?

```
SELECT d.entry_id AS entry_id
   , d.field_id_40 AS body
   , t.title AS title
   , t.url_title AS url_title
   , t.entry_date AS entry_date
   , GROUP_CONCAT(g.tag_name ORDER BY g.tag_name) AS tag
FROM exp_channel_data d
   , exp_category_posts c
   , exp_channel_titles t
   , exp_tagger_links l
   , exp_tagger g
WHERE t.YEAR > '2005'
   AND t.site_id = d.site_id
   AND d.site_id = 9
   AND ( c.cat_id = 95
      OR c.cat_id = 93
      OR c.cat_id = 64
      OR c.cat_id = 24
   )
   AND d.entry_id = t.entry_id
   AND t.entry_id = c.entry_id
   AND t.STATUS = 'open'
   AND l.tag_id = g.tag_id
   AND d.entry_id = l.entry_id
GROUP BY d.entry_id
```

Comment: Use `JOIN`, not `WHERE`, for joining your tables. Then, it will be easy to change an `INNER JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN` to solve your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Switching your JOINS to use the [`JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) syntax, this should provide you with your answer.

```
SELECT d.entry_id AS entry_id
   , d.field_id_40 AS body
   , t.title AS title
   , t.url_title AS url_title
   , t.entry_date AS entry_date
   , GROUP_CONCAT(g.tag_name ORDER BY g.tag_name) AS tag
FROM exp_channel_data AS d
INNER JOIN exp_channel_titles AS t ON d.site_id = t.site_id
   AND d.entry_id = t.entry_id
INNER JOIN exp_category_posts AS c ON t.entry_id = c.entry_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN exp_tagger_links AS l ON d.entry_id = l.entry_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN exp_tagger AS g ON l.tag_id = g.tag_id
WHERE t.YEAR > '2005'
   AND d.site_id = 9
   AND c.cat_id IN (95, 93, 64, 24)
   AND t.STATUS = 'open'
GROUP BY d.entry_id
```

You may also want to look at [A visual explanation of SQL joins.](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)